# Edit war, part 1: With regards to question nr. 11471 about an abusive co-worker

Tags: discussion, specific-question

So, this evening I stumbled upon this question in the reopen queue:

[How to deal with a person who tells me every time that he is better at work than me and always abuses me on this topic?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11471/how-to-deal-with-a-person-who-tells-me-every-time-that-he-is-better-at-work-than?noredirect=1#comment46124_11471)

I remembered it, because I was the one closing it, and leaving a comment asking for clarification. When examining it, I found it now contained a goal that IMO wasn't in line with the comment the OP left:

> @Tinkeringbell, 26 y.o. , he is 30. I am from Europe and he is too, from the same country. I tried to humiliate him in responce but i cant do it so poisonous as he does it. he is a stupid asshole. I would like to shut his mouth and make him suffer, i want him to stop humiliate me or anybody, i want him to go day after day in sadness.

The question was edited, and that edit was approved by reviewers (I missed that fact). I rolled back the edit, because as far as I was concerned, the edit wasn't in line with the original goal of the OP.

Here's the text of the edited question:

> How do I deal with one who belittles me at work at every opportunity?
>
> A colleague at work keeps boasting about his sexual adventures, and my lack of such things, and keeps hurting my self-confidence at every turn. He belittles and insults me , and I feel verbally abused. I am 26 years old, and he is 30. Both of us belong to the same European country.
>
> I'm unable to retaliate effectively as I'm not very eloquent with words. I have to keep working beside him.
>
> How do I get him to stop doing this or even get back at him so that I can get some closure, and put my mind at rest?

I left a comment for the editor, stating that this goal/question was in my opinion not in line with the comment above, *'want him to go day after day in sadness'* doesn't sound like *'I want closure'* to me.

So, questions:

- Was this a good edit?

  - With regard to the little policy we have on questions asking for skills that are harmful to others, like [Pick Up Artistry](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2346/would-the-scope-of-interpersonal-skills-include-pickup/), is asking for ways to get back at people a good goal?
  - Is this edit true to the authors original intent?

Answer (score 5):

(1) The user's edit was unfortunately not true to the author's original intent which is still clearly visible in [comments](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11471/how-to-deal-with-a-person-who-tells-me-every-time-that-he-is-better-at-work-than?noredirect=1#comment45661_11471). Since OP has made his intentions clear on the record, such an edit wouldn't be consistent *even if made by OP.*

(2) So it was a confusing edit, even if the user made it in good faith, and distorted the question by basically changing OP's intent from 'negative' to 'positive', additionally asking for inaccurate answers in the process, so you were right to roll back the edit to the previous version.

(3) Getting back at people is bad IPS and we don't encourage such questions here.

---

In response to the editor's [comment](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/edit-war-part-1-with-regards-to-question-nr-11471-about-an-abusive-co-worker/2577#comment6836_2577) that peer review is expected to detect errors of interpretation or reasoning in edits:

> I cannot always be completely certain that my edits don't change the OP's intentions. But, if I make a mistake, it would always go through a peer-review where it can be rejected if deemed to be improper, which is why I felt that it was a safe edit. – Simpleton

I am sure the edit was suggested in good faith by @Simpleton: unfortunately you missed OP's intention and so did those who approved the edit, mainly because comments are not seen in the review queue, but we do have an [ongoing peer review](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2547/381) of automatic/ approved edits and that's how Tinkeringbell could spot the error, and helpfully reversed the edit before the Q got reopened.

In short, edits can be corrected even after they come into effect. That actually means members can go ahead and suggest any further edits without worrying about making an error (or just make those edits yourself if you have automatic edit privileges), because we have a system to deal with that, and ***we need everyone's input to improve posts here on IPS.SE!***

Comment: +1 for the 3rd point because regardless of author intent or not, it's not a good IPS question to be seeking revenge and to make someone else "go day after day in sadness"

Comment: We had taken a very early stand not to help anyone simply to settle their scores through bad IPS (which is why questions with clearly negative intent get downvoted, closed and deleted for one reason or another), and many other SE sites including English Language and Usage have such policies, thanks @Jess K.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - Agreed. I'm the one who made the suggested edit. I cannot always be completely certain that my edits don't change the OP's intentions. But, if I make a mistake, it would always go through a peer-review where it can be rejected if deemed to be improper, which is why I felt that it was a safe edit.

Comment: @Simpleton well, guess this was just a pile up of mistakes, see also the answer of NVZ below... That's also a problem with the queues, they don't show the comments so it's harder to check... Don't take it too personal, I like the other edit you did :)

Comment: I am sure you did it in good faith @Simpleton, and that's what I said in the answer: *unfortunately* you missed OP's intention and so did those who approved the edit, mainly because comments are not seen in the review queue, but we do have an [ongoing peer review](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2547/381) of automatic/ approved edits and that's how Tinkeringbell could spot the error, and helpfully reversed the edit before the Q got reopened. Please don't let this stop you from suggesting any further edits, because we need *everyone's* input to improve posts here on IPS.SE!

Comment: @Tinkeringbell -I understand, I'm not taking this personally. No worries : ) And I'll try to suggest edits wherever I can.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a reviewer who approved the edit suggestion, and I didn't know of that comment that you mentioned. I only saw the actual edit suggestion and felt like it gives a positive outlook for the question, hence the approval from me.

But seeing this meta I understand that it might have not exactly reflected the OP's intent.

As a frequent editor myself, my policy is that an edit should not change OP's intent.

Comment: I'm in the exact same position. I also approved the edit without seeing the comment. I guess this is a good time to policy myself better in checking comments before approving edits

Comment: @HugoBDesigner But you were a reviewer, not on [this case](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8087), but on [a similar one](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8085).

Comment: I recommend opening the question in another tab and reading the comments for additional context. I find it extremely useful in the reopen votes review queue, and I imagine it would be good for suggested edits as well.

Comment: @Rainbacon Will try that next time.